# Anchor (a) tag download file not working, using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anchor

I want to be able to download a file named approved_leads.zip when clicking on the a tag, but for some reason I keep getting the message "failed - no file". Even though the path looks correct to me.

```
<a href="../../assets/approved_leads.zip" download>Download File</a>
```

And, here's the folder structure of it, right now the a tag is inside the jsx file called "LeadsPage.jsx" and the .zip file inside the assets folder.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your app is getting bundled into the `public` directory and served from there? Because then the zip file needs to be moved there as well.

Comment: That's a good point. However, I just tried it and it didn't seem to work. The strange thing is that even when I put the .zip file into the same folder as the LeadPage.jsx file it's giving me the error message that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: You should import zip file using: `import approvedLead from './src/assets/approved_leads.zip'`
Then pass **approvedLead** in the anchor tag href attribute

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I had thought that I could just link the path to it but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the file that you want to be downloadable. React do not accept this perspective. You can do it like that:

First, import the file with any name,

```js
import MyDownloadableFile from "../../assets/approved_leads.zip"
```

Secondly, you need to give the reference of file to **a** tag,

```js
<a href={MyDownloadableFile} download>Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Hey!
It seems to me next steps will help you:

1. Put your files in public directory.
2. Make sure a file is available by absolute url path.
3. Use that link for an anchor.